# How to parse JSON value from MQTT client to plotly javascript

Tags: javascript, json, plotly

Hi I have this json type data how can I access P , T , F , W and M data using javascript?

```
{"PHILMG":[{"P":"10"}, {"T":"5"}, {"F":"0"}, {"W":"0"}, {"M":"0"}]}
```

so far I tried.

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {
 ss = message.payloadString;
 console.log(ss);
    //  var p = ss.PHILMG.P;
    //  var time = ss.PHILMG.T;
    //  var f = ss.PHILMG.F;
    //  var w = ss.PHILMG.W;
    //  var m = ss.PHILMG.M;

    // var timecollect = [];
    // var windcollect = [];
    // timecollect.push(time);
    // windcollect.push(wind);
    // console.log(windcollect);

    // var data = 
    //   {
    //     type:'scatter',
    //     x: time,
    //     y: w
    //   };

    // Plotly.newPlot(document.getElementById('PhilMg'), data);
```

}

But Im getting an error

```
Object {errorCode: 5, errorMessage: "AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error Message: Cannot r…ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js:19:132)"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse your JSON string with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), then loop over the array and push the keys and values to the `data` which is visualized with `Plotly`.

```js
var message = '{"PHILMG":[{"P":"10"}, {"T":"5"}, {"F":"0"}, {"W":"0"}, {"M":"0"}]}';
var msg = JSON.parse(message);
var x = [];
var y = [];
var i = 0;
var j;
var k;
for (k in msg) {
  for (i = 0; i < msg[k].length; i += 1) {
      for (j in msg[k][i]) {
          x.push(j);
          y.push(msg[k][i][j]);
      }
   }
}

 
var data = [{
    x: x,
    y: y,
    type: 'bar'
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct index of the array you have in your object to reach the respective inner object at each assignment.

```
    //  var p = ss.PHILMG[0].P;
    //  var time = ss.PHILMG[1].T;
    //  var f = ss.PHILMG[2].F;
    //  var w = ss.PHILMG[3].W;
    //  var m = ss.PHILMG[4].M;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the log in developer tools,
If you see this,

> Object {PHILMG: Array[5]}

You should use the index of the array to get the object, then use key to get the value.

If you see this,

> "{"PHILMG":[{"P":"10"}, {"T":"5"}, {"F":"0"}, {"W":"0"}, {"M":"0"}]}"

You should use `ss = JSON.parse(ss)`, and same as above.